# Need help getting certain parts of an RSS feed using Regex

Tags: regex, rss

I'd need to to extract the company name (JTA Connection) before the first 
 and the deadline and location, preferably without the "Deadline:" and "Location:" parts, from the RSS feed below using REGEX.

```
<description>JTA Connection Oy<br /> Työsuhde: <br /> Työn laatu: <br />Deadline: 07.09.2011<br />Location: Avoin<br /></description>
```

I'm a bit lost when it comes to extracting certain parts with regex, so any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Company name :

```
<description>([^<]+)
```

Deadline :

```
Deadline:\s([^<]+)
```

Location :

```
Location:\s([^<]+)
```

Each time, the result you're searching is matched by group 1. You can also use "look behind" feature if your programming language allows it.

You can also match the whole string and get each group individually :

```
<description>([^<]+)<br\s?/>([^<]+)<br\s?/>([^<]+)<br\s?/>Deadline:\s([^<]+)<br\s?/>Location:\s([^<]+)<br\s?/></description>
```

In this case, *company name* is matched by group 1, *deadline* by group 4 and *location* by group 5.

**I assume with this answer that the RSS you are parsing always have this exact structure.
I'd consider using an XML parser if that is not the case**.

Comment: Thank you, this was the way to go and by the way, all the feeds have the same structure.

Answer (score 2):

An RSS file is an xml file, so it is best parsed using an xml parser.  Once you have the description portion, it would be trivial to break it up into an array in most languages and a lot more efficient to compare the start of the strings using the "Word:" to get the data you're interested in.  This just isn't something I would use regex for.